# Given a created linked list with cargos, I need to check if the actual sequence or "train" is valid using a function

Tags: c++, function, validation, linked-list, traversal

Hello i'm doing a project where i need to compare and check if the train that i made is valid, the conditions are given below:

-If any of the following conditions are met, the train is considered invalid:

-OXIDIZER cargo cannot be adjacent to COMBUSTIBLE cargo

-3 COMBUSTIBLE cars cannot be in a row

-5 BIOLOGICAL cars cannot be in a row

-A BIOLOGICAL car can have a RADIOACTIVE on one side ONLY (cannot be RADIOACTIVE -> BIOLOGICAL -> RADIOACTIVE)

My question is, how should i implement it to correctly match the conditions?, and how should i fix it?. this code has no errors, just that it doesn't match what i want it to do, I get what I need to do though just can't implement it correctly. Thank you.

Here is what I have so far:

```
enum CARGO_TYPE { //All of the possible cargo types (or car types)
  BIOLOGICAL,
  POISONOUS,
  COMBUSTIBLE,
  OXIDIZER,
  RADIOACTIVE,
  LOCOMOTIVE,
  CABOOSE
};

// Name: isValid
// PreCondition:  none
// PostCondition: returns a boolean indicating whether the current
//                arrangement of the train is valid
bool Train :: isValid() const{
Car *current = m_head;
Car *traverse = current->getnext();

  //iterates over the linked list, here's my logic
  while(current->getNext() != NULL){
    Car *temp = new Car(cargo)
    //checks the cargo sequence for OXIDIZER adjacent to COMBUSTIBLE
    if(current->getNext()->getType() == OXIDIZER && traverse->getNext->getType() == COMBUSTIBLE){
      return false;
    }
    //checks the 3 COMBUSTIBLE in a row, just sub in COMBUSTIBLE inside
    if(traverse == traverse->getNext()== traverse->getNext()->getNext()){
      return false;
    }
    //checsk the 5 BIOLOGICAL cars in a row
    if((traverse == traverse->getNext())== traverse->getNext()->getNext()){
      return false;
    }
    // checks if BIOLOGICAL only have one RADIOACTIVE on one side.
    if(traverse == traverse->getNext()== traverse->getNext()->getNext()){
    }
  return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: so what function do you have to get the current type of `Car *` and compare it with either `OXIDIZER` or `COMBUSTIBLE`?

Comment: ohh I see where your going here, but it's called getType(), i think your going with along the lines of Car->getType()?

Comment: So if i am getting that right. we have this //checks the cargo sequence for OXIDIZER adjacent to COMBUSTIBLE. so if(car->getType() == OXIDIZER && car->getNext()->getType() == COMBUSTIBLE){ return false;}

Comment: i'm assuming that the current node which is OXIDIZER then we check the next adjacent node and if it's the COMBUSTIBLE, then it's not valid and returns false?

Comment: yes. so to summarize, use `getType()` to compare types. use `getNext()` to get a `Car *`

Comment: Unrelated: Looks like you have a memory leak  at `Car *temp = new Car(cargo)` unless you have something unexpected planned. Why would you need to create a new node in a function that looks like it's supposed to verify existing nodes?

Comment: alright i'll update my code above and can you check if i did it correctly? that way i have a guide on how to fix the rest

Comment: Oh that i was trying to traverse my whole list, so i thought i needed that to change nodes, since i'm not gonna be stuck at the head node all the time, not sure if that's how to do it thought. again still new to C++ so i'l have errors here and there

Answer (score 1):

Following how you were doing it before, you can try this... though didn't compile to check it initially.

```
bool Train :: isValid() const
{
  Car *current = m_head;
  Car *traverse;

  //iterates over the linked list
  while(current->getNext() != NULL)
  {
    traverse = current->getNext();

    //checks the cargo sequence for OXIDIZER adjacent to COMBUSTIBLE
    // Need to check both ways, -O-C- and -C-O-
    if((current->getType() == OXIDIZER && traverse->getType() == COMBUSTIBLE) || 
       (current->getType() == COMBUSTIBLE && traverse->getType() == OXIDIZER)){
      return false;
    }

    //checks the 3 COMBUSTIBLE in a row, just sub in COMBUSTIBLE inside
    if(current->getType() == COMBUSTIBLE && traverse->getType() == COMBUSTIBLE){
      //Need the inner conditional to make sure traverse isnt the 
      //end of the train
      if(traverse->getNext() != NULL && traverse->getNext()->getType() == COMBUSTIBLE){
         return false;
       }
    }

  //check the 5 BIOLOGICAL cars in a row
  if(current->getType() == BIOLOGICAL && traverse->getType() == BIOLOGICAL)
  {
     int count = 2; //already counted the first two in conditional above
     while(traverse->getNext() != NULL && count < 5)
     {
      traverse = traverse->getNext();
      if(traverse->getType() == BIOLOGICAL)
        count++; 
      else
        break;
     }

   if(count == 5)//if 5 biologicals were counted in a row, return false
     return false;
  }

  // checks if BIOLOGICAL only have one RADIOACTIVE on one side.
  if(current->getType() == RADIOACTIVE && traverse->getType() == BIOLOGICAL) 
    if(traverse->getNext() != NULL && traverse->getNext()->getType() == RADIOACTIVE)
      return false

    current = traverse; //continue iterating through train
  }

  return true;//passes everything, train should be good
}
```

Use at own risk, there are better ways of doing what you want... just gave something similar to what you were thinking.